# Can content values insert formulas in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

For instance, here I want to insert the formula `datetime('now', '+63 minutes')`:

```
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("_id", _id);
    cv.put("name", name);
    cv.put("datetime", "datetime('now', '+" + minutes+hours*60 + "minutes'");
    db.insert("table", null, cv);
```

Default behavior is to set the column to the String "datetime('now', '+63 minutes')" instead of calculating the formula.

Comment: why dont you first try and then post error if any

Comment: You can, but only **literally** (i.e.: you **can't use it in a query** as a calculated column): Just insert it as a string value (by escaping the string and doubling the apostrophes). On the other hand, you might want to use a calculated column in a query **directly**. No need to try such naive methods, which will only return errors and delusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`ContentValues` values are bound as literal values and not evaluated as SQL expressions. Under the hood it uses [sqlite variable binding](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html).

As observed in your literal, you get the literal string value in the database.